# Loading several input files into one Dataframe in Scala / Spark 1.6

Tags: scala, dataframe

I'm trying to load several input files in to a single dataframe:

```
val inputs = List[String]("input1.txt", "input2.txt", "input3.txt")

val dataFrames = for (
  i  <- inputs;
  df <- sc.textFile(i).toDF()
) yield {df}

val inputDataFrame = unionAll(dataFrames, sqlContext)

// union of all given DataFrames
private def unionAll(dataFrames: Seq[DataFrame], sqlContext: SQLContext): DataFrame = dataFrames match {
  case Nil => sqlContext.emptyDataFrame
  case head :: Nil => head
  case head :: tail => head.unionAll(unionAll(tail, sqlContext))
}
```

Compiler says

```
Error:(40, 8) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
    df <- sc.textFile(i).toDF()
       ^
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

First, `SQLContext.read.text(...)` accepts multiple filename arguments, so you can simply do:

```
val inputs = List[String]("input1.txt", "input2.txt", "input3.txt")
val inputDataFrame = sqlContext.read.text(inputs: _*)
```

Or:

```
val inputDataFrame = sqlContext.read.text("input1.txt", "input2.txt", "input3.txt")
```

As for your code - when you write:

```
val dataFrames = for (
  i  <- inputs;
  df <- sc.textFile(i).toDF()
) yield df
```

It is translated into:

```
inputs.flatMap(i => sc.textFile(i).toDF().map(df => df))
```

Which can't compile, because `flatMap` expects a function that returns a `GenTraversableOnce[?]`, while the supplied function returns an `RDD[Row]` (See signature of `DataFrame.map`). In other words, when you write `df <- sc.textFile(i).toDF()` you're actually taking each *row* in the dataframe, and yielding a new `RDD` with these rows, which isn't what you intended.

What you were trying to do is simpler:

```
val dataFrames = for (
  i  <- inputs;
) yield sc.textFile(i).toDF()
```

But, as mentioned at the beginning, the recommended approach is using `sqlContext.read.text`.